# How to reference individual native libraries (.so files) BY LINK in Android Studio (gradle)

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have native libraries (.so files) of multiple architectures (armeabi, mips, x86, etc) located on a network drive at \\network\android\[architecture]\*.so

I want to reference **individual** .so files **by link** from this folder, **while specifying architecture** in my Android Studio project.

Example:

let's assume that I have the following library files:

- \\network\android\armeabi\liba.so
- \\network\android\armeabi\libb.so
- \\network\android\mips\liba.so
- \\network\android\mips\libb.so

I can reference both liba.so and libb.so by adding the following line to my project's build.gradle file:

```
android{
    sourceSets{
        main.jniLibs.srcDirs += '\\network\android'
    }
}
```

However, I'm not sure how I'm supposed to go about referencing JUST liba.so while excluding libb.so.

If I do this...

```
android{
    sourceSets{
        main.jniLibs.srcDirs += '\\network\android\armeabi\liba.so'
        main.jniLibs.srcDirs += '\\network\android\mips\liba.so'
    }
}
```

...I get UnsatisfiedLinkErrors (the files aren't referenced).

Is this possible with gradle? Or should I instead just copy files into src/main/jniLibs/[architecture] at build time and then delete them after building? I would prefer to not have to move files around and create unnecessary redundancies.

Thanks for any info!

Answer (score 0):

with gradle you can do eveything you just have to try ;)

i'm not sure that i understood what you want to do but you can try for example something like this:

```
configurations {
    providedCompile.extendsFrom(anyNameArmeabi)
    testRuntime.extendsFrom(anyNameMips)
    //add your own configuration
    anyNameArmeabi
    anyNameMips
}
```

you can configure to what build in config attach your configs, you can add it to provided compile like above, or testRuntime etc.

```
dependencies {
    ...
    anyNameArmeabifiles('${project.getPath()}\\network\android\armeabi\liba.so')
    anyNameArmeabi files('${project.getPath()}\\network\android\armeabi\libb.so')
    anyNameMips files('${project.getPath()}\\network\android\mips\liba.so')
    anyNameMips files('${project.getPath()}\\network\android\mips\libb.so')
}
```

You can also add enviromnment when building to choose what configuration exclude/ include. For example if you somewhere in code add :

```
  if (env == 'armeabi') {
    from(configurations.anyNameArmeabi) {
      include '**'
      into 'somewhere'
    }
  }
```

i dont know how your project looks like so it is hard to help more.

Comment: and im using gradle with java, so there may be some diffs, but main concetps should be same

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just using copy/delete tasks to get this done. I copy the shared libs into the standard shared libs folder structure for the build, then delete when the build is complete.

```
task copySharedLibs << {

    copy {
        from '\\\\network\\android\\armeabi\\liba.so'
        into 'src\\main\\jniLibs\\armeabi'
    }

    copy {
        from '\\\\network\\android\\\\mips\\liba.so'
        into 'src\\main\\jniLibs\\mips'
    }

}

task deleteSharedLibs(type: Delete) {

        delete 'src\\main\\jniLibs\\armeabi\\liba.so', 'src\\main\\jniLibs\\mips\\liba.so'
}

task buildRelease(dependsOn: ['copySharedLibs', 'uploadArchives', 'deleteSharedLibs']) {

    uploadArchives.mustRunAfter copySharedLibs
    deleteSharedLibs.mustRunAfter uploadArchives
}
```

Comment: The down side to this is gradle will copy them every single time even if the copy is not needed. A copy task would get around this. task copySharedLibs (type: Copy)

Answer (score 0):

This should be what you are looking for:

```
android{
    sourceSets{
        main.jniLibs.srcDirs += '\\network\android'
        // this should work but not 100% sure
        filter 'liba.so'
        // or this may also work, might need brackets []
        sourceFiles '\\network\android\armeabi\liba.so'
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. I'm getting a failure to build with message "Could not find method include() for arguments [liba.so] on AndroidSourceSet container." In looking at the Gradle docs, there doesn't appear to be an include method on the AndroidSourceSet object.

Comment: Apologizes then, it is likely a feature that has been added but not adopted yet by the android plugin. Let me look into it.